# Uncaught RangeError при отправке формы с помощью $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post

```
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        if ($(this).valid()) {
            alert("Началась загрузка резюме.");
            $.post('DownloadResumes', { ResumesAmount: $("#ResumesAmount", this) }, function(data) {
                if (data.result === "success") {
                    alert("Резюме успешно загружены!");
                } else {
                    alert("Резюме не загружены");
                }
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                if (data.result === "success") {
                    alert("Резюме успешно загружены!");
                } else {
                    alert("Резюме не загружены");
                }
            });
        } else {
            alert("Некорректный ввод!");
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Сервер возвращает простой JSON-ответ `{"result":"success"}`. Но ещё до возврата ответа возникает ошибка:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

В результате чего после ответа вместо того, чтобы JSON был обработан в `success` или `.done()` функциях, происходит полная перезагрузка страницы, содержащая JSON-ответ. Пробовал использовать `success` и `.done()` по отдельности: результат тот же.

Comment: Просто таким образом показал, что пробовал и так и сяк. Из-за ошибки ни done, ни success не перехватывает json-ответ. Как я уже и писал, пробовал использовать их по-отдельности.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `$("#ResumesAmount", this)` - это объект `jQuery`, а не `Number` или `String`. Как видно в примере, jQuery очень плохо реагирует на такое.

Если вам нужно передавать значение `#ResumesAmount`, то нужно использовать `$("#ResumesAmount", this).val()` (если `#ResumesAmount` - `input`, `textarea` или `select`) или `$("#ResumesAmount", this).text()` (с остальными тегами: `div`, `span` и т.д.).

Если вы соблюдаете правила хорошего тона в HTML-коде (в частности, ID элементов в документе уникальны), то вместо `$("#ResumesAmount", this)` можно просто использовать `$("#ResumesAmount")`.

Сокращенный рабочий пример:

```js
$(function() {
    $("form").submit(function() {
        $.post('DownloadResumes.html', {
            ResumesAmount: $("#ResumesAmount").val()
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<form action="">
    <input id="ResumesAmount" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[Пример в fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/032qtudx/).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, проблема была действительно в этом. Вопрос решён.

Comment: @RRRPro на здоровье. Весьма интересная ошибка в самой jQuery, кстати.